# Accounting for spatial correlations in ROC analysis for image segmentation

Tags: autocorrelation, bias, roc, image-segmentation

Typically, we assume independent samples when performing ROC analysis.

But for image data, e.g. in a segmentation problem, pixels in a neighborhood come from the same image and are spatially correlated.

How does this affect the interpretation of, for example, AUC? How can we take into account these correlations and any subsequent biases to the AUC estimate?

Comment: Would something like this work? https://rdrr.io/cran/spANOVA/